# ¿Como obtener todos los datos de un mismo archivo .json en PHP?

Tags: php, json

Tengo el siguiente archivo .json

```
   {
    "Filmes": [
        {
            "Uuid": "",
            "ImdbId": "tt0023331",
            "Title": "Pesn o geroyakh",
            "Year": "1983",
            "Director": "Joris Ivens",
            "Actors": " Joris Ivens,  Joris Ivens",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0023331\/mediaviewer\/rm3586657792?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
    {
    "Filmes": [
        {
            "Uuid": "aa-bb-cc-dd",
            "ImdbId": "tt0015724",
            "Title": "Dama de noche",
            "Year": "1993",
            "Director": "Eva López Sánchez",
            "Actors": "Rafael Sánchez Navarro, Cecilia Toussaint, Miguel Córcega",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0015724\/mediaviewer\/rm615620352?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Y este es el codigo que me genera el archivo JSON:

```
// 4. Llamada a la funcion read_id()
                $res = $filmes->read_id($filmes->id);

                // 5. Obtiene la cantidad de registros almacenados
                $num =$res->rowCount();

                // 6. Check si hay registros
                if ($num > 0)
                {
                    // 7. Vector-Objeto Filmes
                    $filmes_arr = array();
                    $filmes_arr['Filmes'] = array(); 

                    while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                       extract($row);
                       $filmes_item = array(
                            'Uuid' => $uuid_atto,
                            'ImdbId' =>  $tconst,
                            'Title'=> $primaryTitle,
                            'Year'=> $startYear,
                            'Director' => $director,
                            'Actors' => $actors,
                            'Url' => array(
                            'Poster' => $urlPoster,
                            'Location'=> $urlMovie)
                            );


                        // 8. Volcar los datos de filmes_item a "data"
                        array_push($filmes_arr['Filmes'], $filmes_item);
                    }

                    // 9. Convertir a JSON para imprimir
                    echo json_encode($filmes_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                    file_put_contents($ruta, json_encode($filmes_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), FILE_APPEND);
                } else {
                    // Sin registros
                    file_put_contents($ruta, json_encode(array('Message' => null), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
                }
```

Pero cuando leo con el script en PHP:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/Json/filmes_id.json");
$imdb = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($imdb as $imdbs)
{
     $id = ($imdbs[0]['ImdbId']);
     print_r($imdbs);
}
```

Solo me lee el ImdbId: tt0023331. Para el ImdbId: tt0015724 ya me retorna null.

Me di cuenta que solo sobre el primer objeto JSON realiza la lectura.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Puedes compartir por favor el texto de tu JSON. Aquí una imagen no ayuda para nada, si compartes el texto se puede copiar y hacer pruebas. En la imagen parece como si tuvieras dos objetos distintos en vez de uno. Comparte también el resultado que arrojaría esto: `var_dump($imdb);`  No en imagen sino el texto.

Comment: Me parece que te va a producir un JSON mejor organizado si cambias esto: `array_push($filmes_arr['Filmes'], $filmes_item);` por esto: `array_push($filmes_arr[], $filmes_item);`  así no va a crear varios arrays con la clave `Filmes`. No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

La cuestión es que estás presentando un JSON algo extraño.

He probado a validarlo en [`jsonlint`](https://jsonlint.com)  y no valida.

Lo que más se parecería a un JSON válido sería esto:

```
[{
    "Filmes": [{
        "Uuid": "",
        "ImdbId": "tt0023...",
        "Title": "Pens"
    }]
}, {
    "Filmes": [{
        "Uuid": "",
        "ImdbId": "tt0015...",
        "Title": "Dama de Noche"


    }]
}]
```

Sería en realidad un array, y dentro de él otros objetos cuya clave es `Filmes` y dentro de esa clave otro array.

Para leerlo en PHP el código sería así.

```
/*Cadena de prueba*/
$str=
'
[{
    "Filmes": [{
        "Uuid": "",
        "ImdbId": "tt0023...",
        "Title": "Pens"
    }]
}, {
    "Filmes": [{
        "Uuid": "",
        "ImdbId": "tt0015...",
        "Title": "Dama de Noche"    
    }]
}]'; 

/*Código para leer*/
$json=json_decode($str);  //No pasamos TRUE, es preferible dejarlo como JSON
foreach ($json as $item){
    foreach ($item->Filmes as $filme){ //Array que hay en cada Filmes
        echo "ImdbId: $filme->ImdbId / Título: $filme->Title".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
ImdbId: tt0023... / Título: Pens
ImdbId: tt0015... / Título: Dama de Noche
```

**NÓTESE**  que no he forzado la conversión del objeto a un array pasando `TRUE` en `json_decode`. Lo he dejado como un objeto JSON, porque es lo que es. Luego, a las propiedades se accede mediante la notación `$objeto->propiedad`, es incluso más elegante que `$objeto["propiedad"]`.

---

### Con un JSON mejor estructurado

No sé si depende de ti modificar el JSON que se está produciendo. Si depende de ti, quizá convenga organizarlo de otra manera...

Si el JSON se organiza mejor sería más sencillo de leer. Por ejemplo:

```
/*Ejemplo de JSON mejor estructurado*/
$str=
    '
    {
    "Filmes":[
        {
            "Uuid": "",
            "ImdbId": "tt0023331",
            "Title": "Pesn o geroyakh",
            "Year": "1983",
            "Director": "Joris Ivens",
            "Actors": "Joris Ivens, Joris Ivens",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0023331\/mediaviewer\/rm3586657792?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "Uuid": "aa-bb-cc-dd",
            "ImdbId": "tt0015724",
            "Title": "Dama de noche",
            "Year": "1993",
            "Director": "Eva López Sánchez",
            "Actors": "Rafael Sánchez Navarro, Cecilia Toussaint, Miguel Córcega",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0015724\/mediaviewer\/rm615620352?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
    ';

/*La lectura es más simple*/
$json=json_decode($str);             //No hace falta forzar a array
foreach ($json->Filmes as $filme){   //Accedemos directamente a la propiedad Filmes
    echo "ImdbId: $filme->ImdbId / Título: $filme->Title".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
ImdbId: tt0023331 / Título: Pesn o geroyakh
ImdbId: tt0015724 / Título: Dama de noche
```

Aquí tampoco forzamos la conversión a array, y podemos acceder a cada film haciendo simplemente esto: `$json->Filmes`.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la estructura del JSon no es correcta, ya que solo has de declarar una vez el filmes, y cada film va entre {}, así sería el json correcto:

```
 {
    "Filmes":[
        {
            "Uuid": "",
            "ImdbId": "tt0023331",
            "Title": "Pesn o geroyakh",
            "Year": "1983",
            "Director": "Joris Ivens",
            "Actors": "Joris Ivens, Joris Ivens",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0023331\/mediaviewer\/rm3586657792?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "Uuid": "aa-bb-cc-dd",
            "ImdbId": "tt0015724",
            "Title": "Dama de noche",
            "Year": "1993",
            "Director": "Eva López Sánchez",
            "Actors": "Rafael Sánchez Navarro, Cecilia Toussaint, Miguel Córcega",
            "Url": {
                "Poster": "https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0015724\/mediaviewer\/rm615620352?ref_=tt_ov_i",
                "Location": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```